# Align ggplot bar labels to axis of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like the barplot labels to start at 0 on the y axis. Right now, I can adjust them wrt the end of the bar, but that's not what I want.

```
data.df <- data.frame(Proportions=c(.4,.2,.25,.4,.12,.16),Name=c("Label one","Label two","Label three","Label one","Label two","Label three"),group=c("group.one","group.one","group.one","group.two","group.two","group.two"))
 ex.plot <-
   ggplot(data.df, aes(x=Name,y=Proportions,fill=group))+
   geom_bar(stat='identity')+
   xlab(NULL)+
   ylab(NULL)+
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))+
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("#EDA45E","#DB7365"))+
   guides(fill=FALSE)+
   geom_text(aes(label=Name),angle=90,hjust=1)+
   theme_bw()+
   theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())+
   theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
         axis.title.y = element_blank())+
   facet_wrap(~group,nrow=1)

 plot(ex.plot)
```

[Not what I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD2pK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geom_text(aes(label=Name, y=0), angle=90, hjust=0)
```

`hjust=0` means left-justified.

Answer (score 0):

Map the `y` aesthetic to `0`.

```
...
geom_text(aes(label = Name, y = 0), angle = 90, hjust = 0) +
...
```